# How has Academica changed in response mental health disorders?

Tags: academic-life, health, policy

How do universities handle the ever so growing influx of people that are Neurodivergent, and Neurological disorders? Furthermore, what resources, and protocols are there present at the post-secondary level. For example, in a university that I was attending after going through some depression, and mental distress I asked a graduate coordinator for an incomplete and the response was that the computer science department does not give out incompletes that I would have to medically withdrawal. I imagine that the statistics of individuals suffering from a mental illness has been increasing entering 4-year institutions, and graduate school. I imagine that if many students are like this things would change is there any publication on how mental health is being handled at the university level.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too general. I think that on the whole universities are much more open to accomodations for various limitations than they used to be, but no answer here can provide the information you ask for. That said, I am sorry for what you went through.

Comment: It isn't like there were no neurodivergent people enrolled in universities 40 years ago. What may have changed is that there are better treatments now that make it easier for them to prepare for and complete their studies.

Comment: There is no influx of people with mental illnesses.  In some places and times there has been an increase in the proportion of the population that is enrolling, but it's not specific to mental illnesses or neurodivergence or whatever.  Universities serve a wide variety of students poorly, and a few students very well.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, Universities have to comply with the ADA which encompasses both physical and mental impairment. What that compliance looks like will vary from school to school, and on the granular level even course to course.

Comment: Maybe you can add some details: like when the ADA was enacted, and roughly what it requires?